# Como executar código PHP de Importação de Dados para o site WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, importação, woocommerce

Tenho um código de exemplo para criar um Post de um tipo específico (product do `WooCommerce`) e gostaria de usá-lo para fazer uma rotina de importação de muitos produtos.

```
<?php 

    function createNewProduct() {
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => "Custom Variable Test",
            'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'product'
        );

        $skuu = 'custom-prod-1';
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        echo 'post_id = ' . $post_id;
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $skuu );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', "25" );

        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Gasolina', 'pa_fuel' );
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Ford', 'pa_brand' );

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'search' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');

        // Lendo o Post criado
        $content_post = get_post($post_id);
        $content = $content_post->post_content;

        // $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        // echo '<pre>' . print_r($content, true) . '</pre>';
        // echo '<pre>' . print_r($content_post, true) . '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor abordagem para importar os dados. Quando coloco esta rotina num plugin e Habilito pela interface visual o Wordpress executa o código inúmeras vezes criando registros repetidos. Quando executo o arquivo PHP isoladamente ele acusa erro `Fatal error: Call to undefined function`.

Alguma dica de boa prática a ser usada para este tipo de problema ?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), que roda só na ativação do plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Teste Activation Hook
 */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_sopt_32701' );

function activate_sopt_32701()
{
    // fazer_algo_somente_uma_vez();    
}
```

Ou então, usar [esta implementação](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25667/12615) de `run_once`:

```
/* https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25667/12615 */
function run_once($key){
    $test_case = get_option('run_once');
    if (isset($test_case[$key]) && $test_case[$key]){
        return false;
    }else{
        $test_case[$key] = true;
        update_option('run_once',$test_case);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Modo de usar:**

```
if ( run_once('meu_custom_import') ){
    // fazer_algo_somente_uma_vez();
}

if ( run_once('meu_outro_custom_import') ){
    // fazer_outro_algo_somente_uma_vez();
}
```

No caso de procedimentos de importação, recomendo ir fazendo vários `var_dump($valores); die();` <sup>*</sup> até estar certo que os dados estão todos ok, e só nesse momento deixar o update do banco de dados acontecer.

<sup>* Prefiro o `printf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $variavel, true ) );`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Para este problema de importar produtos do `WooCommerce` existe um plugin muito bom com uma versão free https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/ que possui um Add-on para `WooCommerce`  [https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/).

Este plugin lê seu XML e permite que você use `XPATH` para definir o mapeamento entre seu XML e o modelo de domínio do `WooCommerce`.

Exitem uns videos mostrando como fica facil importar produtos inclusive com `Attributes` (que é o caso de Fuel e Brand no seu exemplo).

Comment: Valeu. Vou testar, obrigado